# C#/WPF: Assign style programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to a project that uses C#/WPF/Telerik-Controls.

There is this style:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" Target="{x:Type Button">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="28"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="28"/>
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Image Source="/MyPrj;component/Images/mybutton.png"
                    x:Name="image"
                    Width="24"
                    Height="24"
                    Margin="-2,-2-2,-1"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In XAML I can use the style like this:

```
<RadButton Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"/>
```

**This works fine**. The button's size is 28x28 pixels and **it displays the defined image**.

Now I want to assign the style programmatically:

```
RadButton button = new RadButton();
button.Style = FindResource("MyButtonStyle") as Style;
```

The program seems to find the style because the button's size is 28x28 pixels.

But it does not show the image! **The button shows the text "Image" instead**.

What am I doing wrong?

TIA!

EDIT:

- Added the fact that the project is using Telerik-Controls.
- Corrected the Style

Comment: image path might be an issue. Try giving the relative path wrt exe location.

Comment: Check the output window. Does it have any messages about the image?

Comment: Check the "Margin" parameter in your image. It's not looking right.

Comment: I removed the Margin from the style. Did not help.

Comment: Nothing in your style looks right to me. What is `Target` ? Where is the `<Setter.Value>` tags for `ContentTemplate` ?

Comment: I checked the output window. It does not have any messages about the image.

Comment: @NovitchiS: I did not write the Style. I'm new to the project. The style is used in many places. And it works fine when used in xaml. But I need to assign it programmatically. Don't know what Target is.

Comment: Try the following URI for your image `pack://application:,,,/MyPrj;component/Images/mybutton.png`.

Comment: @MariusBancila: I tried that. It did not harm the buttons who's styles are assigned in xaml. But it also did not help the button who's style is assigned programmatically.

Comment: Where you wrote your style. Inside the Window.Resources?

Comment: The style is in a file called Styles.xaml.

Answer (score 3):

There is a somewhat unknown quirk with `Images` in `Styles`. By just defining the Image like this, only one single Image will be created, ever, and thus can only appear in one of your buttons. So without really knowing the rest of your code, I *assume* you have two buttons with that style assigned.

What you can do to solve this is to create the image separately with the property  `x:Shared="false"`, and then set the content instead. Then a new Image will be created each time you reference it.

```
<Image x:Key="buttonImage" x:Shared="false" Source="/MyPrj;component/Images/mybutton.png"
       Width="24" Height="24" Margin="-2,-2-2,-1"/>

<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" Target="{x:Type Button">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="28"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="28"/>
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Content="{StaticResource buttonImage}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I changed "<Border Content" to "<Button Content". It did not help.

Comment: Don't do that. In a DataTemplate for a Button you don't want to add a new Button.